# Turquoise waters – A letter from Gladys

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

[image: Empty crossword grid]

Letters from Gladys are geography-themed standalone crosswords. Each puzzle has five thematic answers, which are places, sights or landmarks in or around a certain location (in this case, a peninsula). Each thematic answer is notable enough to have its own article in the English Wikipedia, although not necessarily under the same name that is used here. The goal is to fill the grid, identify the thematic answers and guess the name of Gladys’s destination, which is not indicated in the grid.

> Dear Puzzling,
>
> The place I am visiting today offers a rich history and an astounding amount of natural beauty. I have relaxed at the beach, dived in turquoise waters and trekked deep into the rainforest to see the remains of an ancient civilisation. Can you guess where I am?
>
> Wish you were here!
> Love, Gladys.

**Across**
1. Places for boring exercise in golf, as well as political promises (8,9)
10. Ned enraged with lack of flamenco in Andalusia, say (4,5)
11. Astronaut identified cutting-edge equipment (7)
12. Staying outside as he was shunned for his crime, kidnapping Mike Pence with force (7)
14. Registration of membership for ten (or, for a change, about fifty) people (9)
15. Bolivian people's magic sauce (4)
16. Taking part in Christian extremist's following (4)
18. Humble doctor cured disease at last (6)
22. Principles from Burgundy: The anchorman retorted vacuous messages (5)
23. Retrospective comic performance about the essence of magical talismans (5)
24. Playing uno in cooperation (5)
25. Prestigious stone thrown in great lake once (6)
26. In Burgundy, the news agency that publishes widely used stylebook shows sudden progress (4)
27. Groundbreaking device appearing after the ending of *Das Boot*? (4)
30. Suffering isn't fun – drinking energy drinks ultimately leads to poor health (9)
33. Gladys is trapped in Queens, swinging Colts? (7)
34. A role played by Mr Pacino – he got many of his coworkers in trouble for fixing copiers (7)
35. *Doctor No* given licence to be shown before the initial parts of *Tosca*, an opera by an Italian composer (9)
37. Surprisingly, he rises so large car can provide transport without the use of 33 across (9,8)

**Down**
1. "The work of vandals backfired" – Agency's leading agent, Bond (10)
2. Faith reform sure to be stopped by judge on vacation to tropical destination (4,7)
3. Beethoven's work in craft guild (6)
4. Woman perhaps wanting halo? (3)
5. Disturb First Lady with some music in lift (5)
6. Heard from Aquaman: "Greek sea perturbed, with icy island" (9,4)
7. Maybe Dom Pérignon, having been shown the exit, lost all excitement (7,3)
8. Riveter excited soirée endlessly (5)
9. Part of Johannesburg is very rainy? No (6)
13. They say grill exploded entirely? That leads to deep depression (5,4,4)
17. Damaged tail end of truck inside site of ancient city (5)
19. Czech-Haitian criminal skirted law, essentially leading to ruin (7,4)
20. Secretary is wildly erotic, grabbing bottom in spontaneous passion (10)
21. Emphasise anything from 19 down? (10)
28. One was started in a Munich beer hall placed atop school (6)
29. He plays an instrument that's blue, mixed with red and containing a little bit of green (6)
31. Excitement for expensive coat with gold colour (5)
32. Sister devastated, having lost first of two fathers (5)
36. State supporting Oakland's housing (3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grid, with thematic answers turquoise:

> [image]

Explanations:

Across

> 1. DRILLING PLATFORMS **DRILLING + PLATFORMS** *Places for boring* exercise in golf, as well as political promises (8,9)
> 10. FOLK DANCE **(NED + LACK OF)*** Ned enraged with lack of *flamenco in Andalusia, say* (4,5)
> 11. BUZZSAW **BUZZ + SAW** Astronaut identified *cutting-edge equipment* (7)
> 12. CAMPING **CAIN kidnapping MP with G** *Staying outside* as he was shunned for his crime, kidnapping Mike Pence with force (7)
> 14. ENROLMENT **(TEN OR)* about L MEN** *Registration of membership* for ten (or, for a change, about fifty) people (9)
> 15. MOJO **triple def** *Bolivian people*'s magic sauce (4)
> 16. NEXT **substring** Taking part in Christia**n ext**remist's *following* (4)
> 18. REDUCE **CURED* + (diseas)E** *Humble* doctor cured disease at last (6)
> 22. NORMS **RON< + M(-essage)S** *Principles* from Burgundy: The anchorman retorted vacuous messages (5)
> 23. TIKIS **SKIT< about (-mag)I(-cal)** Retrospective comic performance about the essence of magical *talismans* (5)
> 24. UNION **UNO IN** Playing uno in *cooperation* (5)
> 25. ASTRAL **ST in ARAL** *Prestigious* stone thrown in great lake once (6)
> 26. LEAP **LE + AP** In Burgundy, the news agency that publishes widely used stylebook shows *sudden progress* (4)
> 27. SHOE **HOE appearing after (-da)S** Groundbreaking device appearing after the ending of Das *Boot?* (4)
> 30. UNFITNESS **(ISNT FUN)* drinking E (-drink)S** Suffering isn't fun – drinking energy drinks ultimately leads to *poor health* (9)
> 33. EQUINES **I in QUEENS*** Gladys is trapped in Queens, swinging *Colts?* (7)
> 34. SERPICO **COPIERS*** *A role played by Mr Pacino – he got many of his coworkers in trouble* for fixing copiers (7)
> 35. RIGOLETTO *RIG O LET TO(-sca)* Doctor No given licence to be shown before the initial parts of Tosca, *an opera by an Italian composer* (9)
> 37. HORSELESS CARRIAGE **(HE RISES SO LARGE CAR)*** Surprisingly, he rises so large car can provide *transport without the use of 33 across* (9,8)

Down

> 1. DEFACEMENT **FED< + A + CEMENT** "*The work of vandals* backfired" – Agency's leading agent, Bond (10)
> 2. *ISLA MUJERES* **ISLAM SURE* containing J(-udg)E** Faith reform sure to be stopped by judge on vacation to *tropical destination* (4,7)
> 3. LUDWIG **W in GUILD*** *Beethoven*'s work in craft guild (6)
> 4. NUN **NOUN minus O &lit** Woman perhaps wanting halo? (3)
> 5. PEEVE **(EVE EP)<** *Disturb* First Lady with some music in lift (5)
> 6. *AMBERGRIS CAYE* **AMBER + (GR SEA ICY)*** Heard from Aquaman: "Greek sea perturbed, with icy *island*" (9,4)
> 7. FIZZLED OUT **FIZZ + LED OUT** Maybe Dom Pérignon, having been shown the exit, *lost all excitement* (7,3)
> 8. ROSIE **SOIRE(-e)*** Riveter excited soirée endlessly (5)
> 9. SOWETO **SO WET + O** *Part of Johannesburg* is very rainy? No (6)
> 13. *GREAT BLUE HOLE* **GRATE BLEW WHOLE** They say grill exploded entirely? That leads to *deep depression* (5,4,4)
> 17. *TIKAL* **TAIL* with (-truc)K inside** Damaged tail end of truck inside *site of ancient city* (5)
> 19. *CHICHEN ITZA* **(CZECH-HAITIAN)* minus (-l)A(-w)** Czech-Haitian criminal skirted law, essentially leading to *ruin* (7,4)
> 20. ESCRITOIRE **EROTIC* containing S, plus IRE** *Secretary* is wildly erotic, grabbing bottom in spontaneous passion (10)
> 21. UNDERSCORE **ddef** *Emphasise* anything from 19 down? (10)
> 28. PUTSCH **PUT + SCH** *One was started in a Munich beer hall* placed atop school (6)
> 29. BUGLER **(BLUE* + R) containing G** *He plays an instrument* that's blue, mixed with red and containing a little bit of green (6)
> 31. FUROR **FUR + OR** *Excitement* for expensive coat with gold colour (5)
> 32. SIRES **(SISTER - T(-wo))*** Sister devastated, having lost first of two *fathers* (5)
> 36. GOA **substring** *State* supportin**g Oa**kland's housing (3)

Credit where due: I had the correct *answer* for 4d but no idea of the wordplay; samm82 figured it out. (See comments.) Thanks to Jafe for confirming!

Comment: I think 4D is an &lit - rot13(A(-b)HA, "jbzna creuncf" = ABHA, "jnagvat" = qryrgvba, "UNYB" = B)

Comment: I guess that's possible, though I confess that I hope not :-). rot13(Lrf, n unyb vf genqvgvbanyyl B-funcrq, ohg "unyb" pyhvat "B" srryf n ovg gbb zhpu bs n fgergpu gb zr. Pbhyq "Z25" pyhr "B" orpnhfr gur Z25 zbgbejnl vf xvaqn-fbegn-pvephyne? Pbhyq yvgrenyyl-nal-abha-cyhf-"creuncf" pyhr ABHA?)

Comment: Fair enough - rot13(V xabj gurer ner fbzr jbeqf gung pna genqvgvbanyyl pyhr "B" onfrq ba gurve funcr gung ner frra nf qhovbhf ba CFR (["RTT" naq "EVAT"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossword_abbreviations) pbzr gb zvaq), naq gur "?" nf na vaqvpngvba gung fbzrguvat fgenatr vf hc pbhyq whfgvsl "jbzna creuncf" = ABHA? V crefbanyyl qba'g zvaq vg, ohg nyfb graq gb or n ybg zber yvoreny jvgu pyhrf) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How does rot13("Ab" = B) in 35A? Is it because rot13("Ab" = "mreb" = B)?

Comment: Yes. (I'm not terribly keen on it but I think it's fairly widely used.)

Comment: Samm82 is correct, I'm afraid :) I've definitely seen "halo" used for that purpose in a cryptic before but agree it's pretty weak since it's not something you'd ever find in a dictionary. I've clued that same answer a few times by now in different puzzles and for some reason I don't think I've ever been happy with how it turns out.

Comment: (Answer updated in the light of that information :-). Thanks!)